# Shared Correlation ID with Castle (Windsor) LoggingFacility

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net, castle-windsor, castle

I'm using Castle Windsor and Log4Net and I want to share "correlation IDs" between different services (per transaction/WCF call).
Ideally, this would even span over WCF transactions (a click on the client side generates the ID which is then reused on the server).

It looks like IExtendedLogger and its ThreadProperties are the way to go, but how would I set those?
Is there a better way than creating my own ILoggerFactory and setting the ThreadProperties upon creation?
(Btw, could different LifeStyle settings for the services break the mechanism?)

The docs are unfortunately really sparse... :(

My goal is that my logs would look like this:

```
1111-1111-1111-1111 INFO OrderService: Processing order with ID 8765
8888-8888-8888-8888 INFO CustomerService: Updating address for customer with ID 9999
1111-1111-1111-1111 INFO OrderRepository: Loading order with ID 1234
1111-1111-1111-1111 INFO CustomerRepository: Loading customer with ID 2222
8888-8888-8888-8888 INFO CustomerRepository: Loading customer with ID 2222
...
```

So this would be two different transactions (entry points in OrderService and CustomerService), and even though both use the CustomerRepository (dependency), the context would be kept, so that it would be easy to see which log message belongs to which call/transaction.

Comment: How would you do it? Yes, it would have to be sensitive to lifestyle. What component would have a logger with the correlation id?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're looking at extending `log4net` rather than Windsor or the logging facility...

Comment: Well, I thought I could write my own ILoggerFactory - and then whenever I would create a new ILogger, I would also set the ThreadProperties accordingly. Because they are shared across ILogger instances, right?
I don't think this should be on the log4net side...
If the IExtendedLogger didn't have those properties, I would just have put it in the current ThreadContext...

Comment: So I could have my IOrderProcessingService with dependencies on ICustomerRepositoryService and IOrderRepository and maybe also IShippingService. Ideally, all would just receive their own logger (just as you would have it in any other application), but the log4net appenders would be able to access the correlation ID - for instance by accessing the ThreadProperties. I could use the PerWcfCall() lifestyle to make sure each call would get its own correlation ID. I'll update my original question for some details.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my orginal question now. :)